# AWS SNS not registering successfully executed action from AWS Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created AWS Cloudwatch Alarm on a Target group for my Elastic Load Balancer.

Once the alarm state goes from OK to Alarm it is should send notification to an AWS SNS Topic with a Lambda function as subscriber.

What I have tested:

- The lambda function works with a dummy SNS event
- Publishing a test message to the SNS Topic results in all subscribers being notified
- The CloudWatch Alarm successfully goes into state Alarm.
- The CloudWatch Alarm History says "2019-08-04 13:18:00   Action  Successfully executed action arn:arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:something"

It seems like there is something wrong in the link between the CloudWatch Alarm and the SNS Topic. The SNS topic Access Policy has been configured to "Everyone" and still no luck.

The exact settings on my CloudWatch Alarm

```
Threshold
UnHealthyHostCount > 0 for 1 datapoints within 1 minute

ARN
arn:aws:cloudwatch:eu-west-1:xxxxx:alarm:awsapplicationelb-targetgroup-API-Workers-xxxxxx-High-Unhealthy-Hosts

Namespace
AWS/ApplicationELB

Metric name
UnHealthyHostCount

LoadBalancer
app/Backend-API-HTTPS/xxxxxx

TargetGroup
targetgroup/API-Workers/xxxxx

Statistic
Sum

Period
1 minute

Datapoints to alarm
1 out of 1

Missing data treatment
Treat missing data as bad (breaching threshold)

Percentiles with low samples
evaluate
```

The actions configured for this were selected from a list of "Select an existing SNS topic". I also tried configuring the topic ARN directly. In both cases the configuration of the actions are marked as `valid` by the AWS console.

Comment: what settings exactly did you use in your alarm?

Comment: @danimal I have edited the question with more details on the alarm